# Grails Duplicate Exception handling

Tags: grails

How to catch duplicate key exceptions in Grails . when trying to save existing integer for a unique column constraint, the error is generating while saving/updating a record .

Also used

```
try{
    object.save(flush:true)
}
catch(org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e){
    println e.message
}
catch(org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException ex){
    println e.message
}
catch(Exception e){
    println e.message
}
```

But unable to catch this issue .

> 23:41:13,265 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter:101] Duplicate entry '1' for
>   key 2
>  23:41:13,281 ERROR [AbstractFlushingEventListener:324]
>   Could not synchronize database 
> state with session
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not
>   execute JDBC batch update  at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266) 
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168) 
>   at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
>   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)

Could you please share the solution to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save a record with an id that already exists.

- If id is auto-generated, don't set it manually
- If id is not auto-generated, set it to something else, for example `max(id) + 1`

Comment: No, id is not auto generated and column is a unique key. Its a text field to enter and when user enters existing integer, it will fail to save. This works correctly, but in console i was getting the errors mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

surely no Exception should be thrown for constraint violation, but rather object.save() should return null?  i.e.

```
if(object.save() == null) {
    // save failed
} else {
    // save succeeded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the uniqueness through a Grails constraint, you have to look for a ValidationException. This is thrown when object.validate() fails; Validation is done before any object.save().

```
try {
  object.save(failOnError: true)
}
catch(ValidationException ve) {
  // Do something ...
}
```

But remember: Any constraint violation, for any member variable can cause a ValidationException ... so you have to distinguish yourself.

**Edit:**

This applies, if you use the Grails 1.2 failOnError feature ...

Comment: yeah, but i'm on grails-1.1.2

Comment: Ok, now there are two possibilities: either try the common Grails validation procedure like if(obj.validate()) { obj.save() } else { obj.errors.each { // doh, there are errors ... } } (like Ali G mentioned) or a simpler and cleaner 'grails upgrade' ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same problem so maybe not a complete answer but what you can do is to force validation and look in the errors, identify the case and place the actions you want:

```
if(instance.validate()) {
    //everything ok 
} else {
    instance.errors.each {
            //identify the case and place actions
    }
}
```

Also note that error is: className.propertyName.unique

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it should work:

```
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

try {
    domainInstance.save(flush: true)
} catch(DuplicateKeyException e) {
    // ...
}
```